# How to put a DLL file into the .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Sorry if this is an obvious question, but I'm new to C# and am trying to use 2 dll's for a project. Where do I put them?

I tried to add SoundTouch.dll as a reference in an empty C# project, but Visual Studio said to make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component. I was suggested to put the dll's into the \bin\debug path, but where is that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it a Win32 DLL or a COM DLL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each project should have it's own \bin\debug (and \bin\release) directory structure under it's project directory, but they will not be created until you Build the project. As for the invalid assembly, it sounds like your dll has either become corrupted or is not a valid .NET assembly.

Edit: Looking at the SoundTouch website, someone has already created a wrapper for this dll suitable for use with C# and it can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/practicesharp/source/browse/trunk/PracticeSharpApp/SoundTouch/)

Comment: Awesome, thanks, RideTheWalrus! So I put the SoundTouch.dll in the project's folder, say it's called \SoundTouchTest\bin\Debug, so is that right? And where would I put SoundTouchSharp.cs? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, \SoundTouchTest\bin\Debug should be fine for the dll. I would include SoundTouchSharp.cs in the project source code folder (in your example '\SoundTouchTest') and add it to the project by right clicking in the Solution Explorer and selecting Add->Add Existing Item.

Comment: Awesome, glad that should work. I just made the .cs file into a DLL and stuck it in the same location, so should that work? I might also create a new question as to how I can access the methods in the libraries soon as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, that should work. Be aware that this will only find the dll for the Debug configuration. If you want to build under the Release configuration, you will need to copy your dll to \bin\Release.

Comment: Perfect, guess that would be good to put those in there for safe measure. Thank you so much for your help, RideTheWalrus! :)

Answer (score 0):

If your DLL is a .NET or COM DLL, you can simply add a reference in Visual Studio.  For details on that procedure see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.110).aspx

If the DLL is a Win32 DLL (does not expose a COM interface) you can interface with it via the Platform Invoke (P/Invoke) mechanism.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

When using P/Invoke the DLL must reside in a location that can be resolved by the .NET runtime, and you use the DllImport attribute to "pull" entry points from the DLL into your C# code, e.g.

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint="puts")]
```

.NET will search for the Win32 DLL in the same directory where the .exe is located.  If you build under Visual Studio, a folder will be created under your project folder

> bin\debug

for a debug build, or for a release build

> bin\release

Comment: Thanks, Eric J! So if VS didn't let me add a reference to it by giving me this error message, would it be best to use P/Invoke?